# How do I open the link to my Github repo by running a command from the terminal?

Tags: git, terminal

I want to visit the webpage for my repo:

`Github.com/myUsername/myRepoName`

After navigating in my terminal to the `myRepoName` directory, can I run a command to open that link in my browser?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I am on MacOS — but Windows and/or Linux users may want an answer to this question, too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bash script that will work for both ssh and https URL.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Script to open the GitHub page of the current repository in the default browser

fetch_url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
# outputs 'git@github.com:some-name/some-repo-name.git' or 'https://github.com/some-name/some-repo-name.git'


if [[ $fetch_url == *"https"* ]]; then
    github_url="${fetch_url%.git}"
else
    # Split the URL on ':' and get the 2nd portion
    url_portion="$(echo "$fetch_url" | awk -F':' '{print $2}')"

    # Remove the .git from the end of the URL
    url_portion="${url_portion%.git}"

    # Construct the final GitHub URL
    github_url="https://github.com/"$url_portion
fi

xdg-open "$github_url"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

Such a functionality is not built-in to Git, but it's easy to implement as an alias or script-based command.

#### Caveat

The exact answer to your question will depend on your operating system and which Git distro you're using, and what type of URL you use in your repos, but at least one of my two solutions below should be fairly easy to adapt to most systems.

#### Solution option 1: create an alias

Here is a alias that works in my Git for Windows `~/.gitconfig` assuming an https URL for my remotes, and with no error checking:

```
[alias]
    browse-remote = !/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe $(git remote show -n origin | grep Fetch.URL | sed 's/.*http/http/')
```

In Git Bash, I then CD into a repo and type `git browse-remote` to launch the remote in Chrome.

If you want to use this idea, you'll have to set the browser path correctly, and make sure the part extracting the URL is working correctly on your machine.

#### Solution option 2: write a script

Here is a script with some error checking that works more nicely. Tested in Git Bash on Windows, but should be easy to adapt to Linux or Mac.

Call this file `git-browse-remote`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set this to your browser
BROWSER='/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'

set -o pipefail
URL=$(git remote show -n origin | grep Fetch.URL)
if [[ $URL =~ http ]]; then
   # remote URL is already and http(s) link, just strip the prefix
   URL=$(echo "$URL" | sed 's/.*http/http/')
elif [[ $URL =~ "git@" ]]; then
   # remote URL is git@host:path, change it to https://host/path
   URL=$(echo "$URL" | sed -E 's|.*git@(.*?):|https://\1/|')
else
   echo git-browse-remote: Could not extract repo URL from the output of \"git remote show -n origin\"
   exit 1
fi

"$BROWSER" "$URL"
```

Run `chmod +x git-browse-remote` and place the file somewhere on your PATH.

Then typing `git browse-remote` will open the remote in your browser if it's an http(s) link, convert a git@ URL to https and open it if it's an ssh link, or issue an error message if you're not inside a repo.

Heck, I like this solution enough, I just installed in on my own machine. What a good idea, thanks for asking the question!

#### Edits

- The script above now handles both ssh and https remote URLs.
- Both solutions now use `git remote show -n origin` with the `-n` so that we don't unnecessarily contact the remote when just extracting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a cli ([to-where-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-where-cli)) that can help you solve this problem, just execute:

```
npm install -g to-where-cli
// open current remote branch
tw git open 
// open master/main remote branch
tw git open -m
```

github: https://github.com/skypesky/to-where-cli

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-where-cli

Answer (score 0):

Quick alias to be placed in `.zshrc`/`.bashrc`.

```bash
alias remote='open "$(git remote get-url origin | sed "s/\.git$//")"'
```

**Note**: `open` is designed for files/dirs/URLs on MacOS. Linux users may need to substitute with `xdg-open`.